# How can I sync my with Zune HD using the Zune software?

Tags: sync, zune, zune-software, zune-hd

I have a Zune HD and a subscription to Zune Marketplace. I am able to sync non-DRM music, but it fails for anything from the marketplace. It click "Sync with Zune" or drag the album icon to the Zune icon, but it never works.

It says "Added 1 album" briefly, then when I go to **Device** >> **Summary**, all the songs I've tried to add are listed under "Not Added".

I click "start sync", and nothing happens.

What could I be doing wrong?

I'm using Windows 7, and the most recent versions of the Zune and Zune HD software.

Answer (score 1):

You should check and make sure you Zune HD is linked to your Marketplace account.  Go to **Settings**->**device**->**Linking**.  You should see a screen similar to the one below.  If your Zune HD is not enabled for the marketplace, that would explain why the marketplace files were not syncing.

[image]

Comment: Good guess, but my zune is indeed linked to the marketplace account. It says "Your device is enabled for marketplace."

Comment: Well, I was hoping it would be an easy solution like that.  I can't think of anything else to would cause the issue.  Have you tried asking in the Zune forums?  You may get some better suggestions from there.  http://forums.zune.net/33/ShowForum.aspx